# How to get more details about duplicate python packages as listed by pip list

Tags: pip

`pip list -u` shows duplicate packages

> qt5-applications  5.15.2.2.2
> qt5-applications  5.15.2.2.2

How do I find out if these are duplicates or not?
If they are how do I fix the pip index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to think through it and it may have just accidentally downloaded the packages twice. You could try to uninstall the package, and then list it and see if it's still duplicated?

From: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/

Command to uninstall

```
python -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
```